# Sum property based on existance in list and quantity

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I am currently summing the value of the SIZE property of my Object based on the existence of its NAME in my list SOURCEFIELDS (see code).

```
string[] SourceFields = MergeParameters
  .Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

int OverallLength = MainFields
  .FindAll(FO => SourceFields
     .Any(List => FO.Name.Equals(List)))
  .Sum(FO => FO.Size);
```

My issue is, if a value appears in SOURCEFIELDS twice (which is possible), I need the value to be doubled (or however many times it appears).

Is this possible with a linq query? I would like to avoid nested loops if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Join` extension method:

```
int OverallLength = MainFields.Join(SourceFields, x => x.Name, y => y,
    (x, y) => x).Sum(x => x.Size);
```

By the way, it is better to call `SourceFields.Contains(FO.Name)` instead of `SourceFields.Any(List => FO.Name.Equals(List))`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] SourceFields = MergeParameters.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    int overallLength = MainFields.Select(mf => SourceFields.Count(sf => sf == mf.Text) * mf.Size).Sum();
```